# Can I query device tree items without creating a platform device?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-tree

I am writing a kernel module intended to functionally test a device driver kernel module for an ARM+FPGA SOC system. My approach involves finding which interrupts the device driver is using by querying the device tree. In the device driver itself, I register a platform driver using `platform_driver_register` and in the `.probe` function I am passed a `platform_device*` pointer that contains the `device` pointer. With this I can call `of_match_device` and `irq_of_parse_and_map`, retrieving the irq numbers.

I don't want to register a second platform driver just to query the device tree this way in the test module. Is there some other way I can query the device tree (perhaps more directly, by name perhaps?)

Comment: Do you know which bus it is on? If so maybe you can use [subsys_dev_iter_init](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/bus.c#L1060) and subsys_dev_iter_next to iterate over the bus and get a handle on the device pointer

Comment: According to the device tree it's on the sopc bus.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/40928373/2007944

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've found so far, and it seems to work. [`of_find_compatible_node`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/base.c#L835) does what I want. Once I have the `device_node*`, I can call [`irq_of_parse_and_map`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/irq.c#L30) (since [`of_irq_get_byname`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/of/irq.c#L410) doesn't seem to compile for me). I can use it something like the following:

```
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_irq.h>
....
int get_dut_irq(char* dev_compatible_name)
{
    struct device_node* dev_node;
    int irq = -1;
    dev_node = of_find_compatible_node(NULL, NULL, dev_compatible_name);
    if (!dev_node)
        return -1;
    irq = irq_of_parse_and_map(dev_node, 0);
    of_node_put(dev_node);
    return irq;
}
```